# Best way to manage git tracked and ignored files across multiple devices?

Tags: git, github

I run a windows 10 laptop with has all my github & bitbucket hosted original git repository code. I use Sourcetree gui app to manage and work with my git repos.

The dilemma I have is for traveling purposes, I just got a lighter lower spec'd windows 10 laptop and need to be able to work with all my local git repo code. So what's the best way to keep everything in sync across 2 windows 10 laptops ?

Easy part is I could just git clone /pull from github/bitbucket to the new laptop to work on code. But the tricky part is alot of the git repos' local code has git ignored folders/files/code which isn't tracked but still critical to working with and developing for the git projects. Also alot of projects have multiple branches so I do switch between branches alot.

The current structure usually for a git project is

```
.git
ignored
codefiles
codefiles-ignored
```

- ignored is a directory which has everything not tracked
- codefiles are tracked files
- but occasionally i have some ignored code files outside of ignored directory which aren't tracked as well ie. codefiles-ignored

I have 307 git projects with 8.9 GB of data which is tracked + ignored and I guess I need to better organise my git projects. Curious what other folks are doing for such situations ?

thanks

Comment: You could use git the mirror a project inside a directory, so even in the case you forgot the fetch that individual project,you still have a copy.This can be done using `git clone --mirror <repo>`,while this wouldn't solve your non tracked file issues (How would a git repo with missing files help out other developers?),it could help you out when you just need the repo (you could also configure SourceTree to automatically fetch every X minutes).I also have writting in the past [a blog post](http://www.competa.com/blog/making-backupmirror-github-repositories) how to backup all your github repos

Comment: Cheers will check out your blog post too. I am the sole developer for all the git projects so no one else is pushing commits to them but me.

Comment: Is there a good reason why project critical code is ignored? Multiple branches are not a problem as every pull will fetch all remote branches. For the organizing question: Do you have a lot of similar projects? Do your projects contain a lot of non-code files? More information makes it easier to answer.